# Migrate nextcloud sqlite database to mysql inside docker

Tags: docker, mysql, sqlite, nextcloud

migrate sqlite to mariadb inside a docker image?

I installed the docker-compose example from the nextcloud readme (the [base version with apache](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker#base-version---apache)) but that one still uses sqlite, although there is created a db docker image as well, but it is not used.

How do I migrate the sqlite to the created db-docker image?

I tried:

```
docker-compose exec --user www-data app php occ db:convert-type --all-apps mysql nextcloud 127.0.0.1 nextcloud
```

which asks for the database password then, but the password I initially set in `docker-compose.yml` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer how to migrate but I found out:

### how to install nextcloud with mysql in docker

If you have a broken installation, delete it with

```
docker-compose down
```

this deletes the containers but keeping the data in volumes.
If you really want to start over, delete the volumes also.

You can delete the volumes using the command:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

or

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

WARNING: This deletes all your data!

This deletes all your named volumes, which were declared in your docker-compose file as well as anonymous volumes which are attached to your container.

Next, restart the docker installation with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

now you will have this screen on your web access:

[image]

There is a small link **Storage & Database**  the middle. click on it and you can select mysql as database backend this time ;)

[image]

For the database use `db` as **host** and `nextcloud` as **table** and **user name** and enter the `MYSQL_PASSWORD` from your  `docker-compose.yml`.